# Extracting P&ID Reference and the drawing number from a PDF Isometric drawing into excel

Tags: pdf

There are more than 8,000 PDF files containing PIPING ISOMETRIC drawings of a process plant. These isometric drawings contain Process and Instrumentation Diagram reference (P&ID). Each file has a unique drawing number. I want to extract this drawing number as as well as the P&ID drawing numbers in an excel file. There is no provision here to attach a sample file but it looks something like this.

P&ID: MD-513-1A00-EG-PR-PID-2035       ;        DWG: MD-513-1A00-ISO-CWR-AA22-0401-23

Can anyone please help. It would save me a lot of time. Thanks in advance

Comment: This question is better suited for [SU]. If you post it there, remove it here (no crossposting among SE sites). But you also need to write a better question. It is irrelevant what the data *means* ("PIPING ISOMETRIC drawings"), you need to describe **what format the data is in**. Adding a screenshot of the PDF might help.